How can I calculate the percentage of requests from the total number of requests that are completed in less than one second? Spring boot
I am trying to calculate such percentage but i am getting wrong values (several results are greater than 1 (or 100%))
(sum(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{application="my-api",le="$le_value"}) by (uri)*100)/sum(http_server_requests_seconds_count{application="my-api"}) by (uri)
What  am i doing worng?

It should not happen. _bucket should always be not greater than _count. Could you have some kind of inconsistency in your metrics? Maybe some load balancer between Prometheus and application?
